# How to pull image from Amazon UK

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to download the hi-res pictures from Amazon.co.uk. I tried the code given in the
[thread][1] and I am getting some issues.

the code by @QHarr works well for given Amazon.in website but when I try for Amazon.co.uk the

.querySelector("#landingImage").getAttribute("data-old-hires") returns nothing. here is the code I am testing.

```
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim Html As HTMLDocument, results()
    Set Html = New HTMLDocument
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/product/B01GFJWHZ0", True
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            .Cells(1, 2) = Html.querySelector("#productTitle").innerText
            .Cells(1, 2).Offset(0, 1) = Html.querySelector("#landingImage").getAttribute("data-old-hires")
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

any idea what exactly I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the response html is mangled. You can easily regex out that bit from the response string however.

Note that the async argument is also set to False to allow time for data to load. I'm somewhat surprised your code got as far as you said it did. It should also have tripped over on the fact there is no match for that selector in the HTMLDocument.

```
Public Sub GetInfo()
    'tools > references > Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Dim re As Object, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, xhr As Object, s As String

    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    re.Pattern = """hiRes"":""(.*?)"""
    
    With xhr
        .Open "GET", "https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/product/B01GFJWHZ0", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        s = .responseText
        html.body.innerHTML = s
    End With
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells(1, 2) = html.querySelector("#productTitle").innerText
        .Cells(1, 3) = re.Execute(s)(0).SubMatches(0)
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Regex:

[image]

Comment: Thanks and yes the async was left to True as I was testing different options.  I just converted your code into a vba/excel function to get the image url through asin.  I tried it for a list of 14 asins which hangs the excel program while its processing.  I used DoEvents multiple times to avoid the situation but not improved much.  The problem is that I am planning to run the script on a table with 100s of such values.  any tip? here is my code.

Comment: `With xhr`
       `DoEvents`
        `.Open "GET", strUrl, False`
        `DoEvents`
        `.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"`
        `DoEvents`
        `.send`
        `DoEvents`
        `s = .responseText`
        `html.body.innerHTML = s`
    `End With`